# How to display latin characters in vbscript MsgBox

Tags: vbscript, messagebox

I have a vbscript that open message box, but I'm making an spanish version of the program and the latin characters are not displaying well:

```
MsgBox "No se ha instalado la Consola de Administración pues debe tener instalado Internet Explorer 8 o superior.", vbExclamation, "Atención"
```

But when I execute the script this is what is displayed:

[image]

As you can see, the Latin characters are not well formatted, does someone could advise me how to fix it?

Comment: I have read several comments that state that vbs already works in unicode and that it is up to the available fonts on the system to display text properly. Your code displays properly on my system which is Unilingual English OS.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is with encoding, I don't know if it is my file that is in ANSI format and then vbscript engine interprets it as UNICODE converting the characters incorrectly, How do I know in what encoding format is my file?

Comment: To ensure your file is unicode you can open it with native windows notepad and [save as unicode text](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/2553/20100321214435.jpg).

Comment: thanks @omegastripes this could be useful in the future for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the chr(#) equivalent

```
MsgBox "No se ha instalado la Consola de Administraci" + chr(242) + "n pues debe tener instalado Internet Explorer 8 o superior.", vbExclamation, "Atenci" + chr(242) + "n"
```

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I changed from your answer is the chr(242) to chr(243) which is the correct one. It works very well, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i saved the vbs file encoded in ANSI (option available in the "save as" dialog box in notepad). It worked fine for me and spared me the hassle of using chr(#) (yes i'm lazy)

context : script running on windows 10 virtual machine on debian host.