# how can I assign Chinese characters to a string variable in VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript

as the title say I want to know if it possible to assign  Chinese characters to a string variable in VBSCRIPT
I tried to assign some Chinese characters to a variable but when I msg box the variable it shows some  weird
characters  .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display latin characters in vbscript MsgBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25674609/692942)

Answer (score 1):

```
Msgbox "繌"
```

You need to save the vbs file as Unicode in Notepad's Save As dialog Encoding drop down.

Comment: In notepad windows 10 save as codification "Unicode" or "UTF16-LE".

Answer (score 1):

Since VBScript `InputBox()` function already accepts Unicode text, and String values are Unicode anyway, We can convert characters like this :

---

***Unicode_Converter.vbs***

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Input,i,OutPut,OutPutResult
Title = "Convert Unicode characters"
Input = InputBox("Enter a character or a sentence to get its Corresponding Unicode Code !",Title,"")
If Input = "" Then 
    Wscript.Quit()
Else 
    For i = 1 To Len(Input) 
        If i <> Len(Input) Then 
            OutPut = OutPut & "ChrW(" & AscW(Mid(Input,i,1)) & ")" & "&" 
        Else 
            OutPut = OutPut & "ChrW(" & AscW(Mid(Input,i,1)) & ")" 
        End if 
    Next 
End If

MsgBox "Unicode = " & OutPut & vbcrlf &_
"Result = " & Eval(OutPut),vbInformation,Title

OutPutResult = InputBox(Eval(OutPut),Title,OutPut)

'Example :
MsgBox chr(34) & "Hello World" & chr(34) & " in English"  & vbCrlf &_
"Translated wih Google in Chinese like this " &_
 chr(34) & ChrW(20320)&ChrW(22909)&ChrW(-244)&ChrW(19990)&ChrW(30028) & chr(34),vbInformation,Title
```